# Add an element in listbuffer into a map (update a map)

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and I have a listbuffer in a map with this structure:

```
class Person(var name: String, var age: Int,note: ListBuffer[Note])
class Note(
  email: String,
  note:  Int)

var m = Map[Tuple3[Int,Int,Int],Person]()
```

How can I update the map to add a new element into a listbuffer.

Comment: you can try to do it

Comment: Already tried, but no chance. what I want is just a guide!! with what I have to stard cuz I'm very confused

Comment: So show us what have u tried

Comment: m((1,1,1)) = (note=  ListBuffer(email= "test@gmail.com",
  note=  2))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should strongly consider using `case` classes in Scala - they give you a lot of good stuff for free. Assuming you do change your classes to case classes the following will achieve what you want:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

case class Note(email: String, note:  Int)
case class Person(var name: String, var age: Int,note: ListBuffer[Note])


val n1 = Note("foo@gmail.com", 4)

val c1 = Person("John", 20, ListBuffer(n1))

val m = scala.collection.mutable.Map[(Int,Int,Int), Person]()

m += ((1,1,1) -> c1)

val n2 = Note("bar@gmail.com", 40)

m += ((1,1,1) -> c1.copy(note = c1.note += n2))

println(m)

res1: scala.collection.mutable.Map[(Int, Int, Int),Person] = Map((1,1,1) -> Person(John,20,ListBuffer(Note(foo@gmail.com,4), Note(bar@gmail.com,40))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a ListBuffer separately with as many notes as you want. Then simply create the map as below:

```
val lb = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer(new Note("s@s.com",1), new Note("d@d.com",2))
Map((1,2,3) -> new Person("samar",0,lb))
```